# How to set up plugins, e.g. scalajs, for subprojects in Play 2.2?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, scala.js

Play Framework [manual](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTSubProjects) for sub-projects says that `project` folder inside the sub-project will not be parsed. This makes impossible to set sbt plugin and use its settings in sub-project's `build.sbt` (example of desired configuration which is impossible: [scalajs](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/sbt/setup.html))

Is there a way besides global plugins setting to achieve required configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been always like this that the (meta)project under `project` can only be at the top-level /root module.

If you want to define a plugin for the multi-module project, `addSbtPlugin` in `project/plugins.sbt` and add the settings to appropriate `build.sbt` of a module.

You don't have to add the tasks and settings to all the projects in a multi-module build.